# Reading a 3.9GB zip file using c# .net4.5 ZipArchive System.IO.Compression

Tags: c#, zip, .net-4.5, system.io.compression, c#-ziparchive

When I try to read the files contained in a large zip file (expands to 3.9GB) using ZipArchive, I get an InvalidDataException exception "The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method" on the StreamReader line.

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zippedFileName))
{
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(entry.Open()))
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The same code works file for a 600M (extracted) zip file.

Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: I'm guessing it's Zip64, 3rd party libraries like DotNetZip support it, but it's probably not supported by the ZipArchive class

Comment: @Martheen  Thanks.  I will look into DotNetZip.

Comment: This *might* be an issue with .NET memory (just a guess), try setting `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` in app.config. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element for details.

Comment: @BurnsBA  Thanks for the suggestion, I will give it a try and let you know if it works.

Comment: @BurnsBA I added <runtime><gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" /></runtime> to the app.config file, but it didn't help.